# How to retrieve the last message of each conversation?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Please consider the following [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2e3db).

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts;
CREATE TABLE contacts (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS conversations;
CREATE TABLE conversations (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    contact_id INT CHECK (contact_id > 0) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(contact_id) references contacts(id)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS messages;
CREATE TABLE messages (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    contact_id INT CHECK (contact_id > 0),
    conversation_id INT CHECK (conversation_id > 0) NOT NULL,
    body TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(contact_id) references contacts(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(conversation_id) references conversations(id)
);

INSERT INTO contacts (name) VALUES ('John');
INSERT INTO contacts (name) VALUES ('Jane');
INSERT INTO contacts (name) VALUES ('Joe');

INSERT INTO conversations (contact_id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO conversations (contact_id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO conversations (contact_id) VALUES (3);

INSERT INTO messages (contact_id, conversation_id, body) VALUES (1, 1, 'Hi');
INSERT INTO messages (contact_id, conversation_id, body) VALUES (1, 1, 'How are you?');
INSERT INTO messages (contact_id, conversation_id, body) VALUES (NULL, 1, 'I am well, how are you?');
INSERT INTO messages (contact_id, conversation_id, body) VALUES (2, 2, 'Hi there');
INSERT INTO messages (contact_id, conversation_id, body) VALUES (2, 2, 'How are you doing?');
INSERT INTO messages (contact_id, conversation_id, body) VALUES (NULL, 2, 'Cannot complain');
INSERT INTO messages (contact_id, conversation_id, body) VALUES (3, 3, 'How is the weather?');
```

I'm wondering how we can query for all of the last messages in a conversation. To be clear, what query would return the following results?

```
//messages
id  contact_id  conversation_id body
3   (null)      1               I am well, how are you?
6   (null)      2               Cannot complain
7   3           3               How is the weather?
```

Furthermore, is there a way to only retrieve the last message for a conversation that has a `contact_id`?

```
//messages
id  contact_id  conversation_id body
2   1           1               How are you?
5   2           2               How are you doing?
7   3           3               How is the weather?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one should be

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (conversation_id)
       id, contact_id, conversation_id, body
FROM messages
ORDER BY conversation_id, id DESC;
```

This assumes that the ordering is by `id`.

To exclude the messages without `contact_id`, add the `WHERE` condition

```
WHERE contact_id IS NOT NULL
```